# Insert into table if not exists from another table

Tags: php, sql, database

How would I instantiate an id in table 'address', where one does not exist? Say i have id 1,2,3,5. Introduce an id of 4 but on a larger scale of several thousand. Using MySql in phpMyAdmin. I'm inserting data from a table called funeralhome_address with a column called 'funeralhome' as an int, and within each entry that int links to a table called 'address'. I'm updating the database and need to insert an id into address with the value from funeralhome_address. Just need the logic , any helps welcome. Thank you.